# FZS600 won't start and gauges keep turning on and off

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, yamaha, gauges

I have a 2003 Yamaha FZS600 that lately started to drain the battery while it's not in use for 2-3 days. I bought the battery in this year's February and if I charge it it does its job.
Yesterday I wasn't able to start the motorcycle normally again so I jumpstarted it (works & goes perfectly that way). After a few miles I noticed that instruments are going off and on again. The headlight stays on, engine runs perfectly though.
When I hit the PASS light or switch on and off the headlights it does that almost everytime too.
Any ideas where to start checking things?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like your bike isn't charging the battery. I don't know about a bike, but when the battery starts getting low on a car, it can cause the issues you're talking about with the gauges going wonky. Put a multimeter on the battery with the engine running and see what it reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips! I ended up at my mechanic and turned out the generator regulator was faulty. There was no charge on my battery so it drained totally, I had to replace that too. But finally with my new regulator and battery, everything just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wiring harness, pull the tank and disconnect the main harness connection, visually inspection and contact cleaner might help. Sounds like you have a failing connection from battery to fuse block, the increased power draw when you energize the lights is an indication of improper current flow.